# Simplification of an expression

Tags: measure-theory, integration

How do I simplify the following expression?
$$\displaystyle \frac{\int_q^1 w(s) \int_0^s e(\xi) d\xi ds}{2\int_q^1 w(s) ds} p$$
where $w(t)$ is nondecreasing $w(t)>0$ on $(q,1]$ , $e :(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $e\in L(0,1)$,
and $\displaystyle\frac12<p<q<1$

Please help me.  Thank you.

Comment: i need to simplify this integration $$\displaystyle \frac{\int_q^1 w(s) \int_0^s e(\xi) d\xi ds}{2\int_q^1 w(s) ds} p$$

Comment: In which way do you want to simplify it?

Comment: i want to transform $\displaystyle \frac{\int_q^1 w(s) \int_0^s e(\xi) d\xi ds}{2\int_q^1 w(s) ds}$ into an integral $ds d\xi$

Answer (score 1):

Changing the order if integration gives
$$ \int_q^1 w(s) \int_0^s e(\xi) d\xi ds = \int_0^q e(\xi) \int_q^1 w(s)\, ds d\xi + \int_q^1  e(\xi)\int_{\xi}^1 w(s)\, ds d\xi .$$

Note that, the first integral on the right hand side can be written as

$$ \int_0^q e(\xi)d\xi \int_q^1 w(s)\, ds = \int_q^1 w(s)\, ds\int_0^q e(\xi)d\xi.  $$

Plot the region to see how the first equation derived.

**Added:** Plot the region $ \xi(s) = s $ where $ q \leq s \leq 1 $. Then to  change the order of integration, consider taking a horizontal strip and notice that the horizontal strip will be bounded below by two different functions, namely, $s=q$ and $s=\xi$. Accordingly, find the limits for $\xi$.

Comment: i don't understand , how you have done that ?

Comment: Beghorbal please

Comment: ok, we dont use Fubini ?